# Selecting pairs of html elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with some server code that is generating html that looks something like:

```
<input type="radio" />
<label>something</label>

<input type="radio" />
<label>something</label>

<input type="radio" />
<label>something</label>

<input type="radio" />
<label>something</label>
```

I want to wrap each pair in a span but I can't figure out a way to select pairs of elements on jquery in order to use `wrapAll()` on them. I can't change the html that I am working with. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).next('label').add(this).wrapAll('<span>');
});
```

1. `next` will find the closest sibling element.
2. `add` will add the matched item to the collection.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrCRy/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<span>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$("input+label") might well be helpful.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: it selects all labels that are immediately preceded by an input (pairs), what you do with this afterwards is up to you ;)